# Best solution to POST data to an iFrame on a different page?

Tags: html, post, iframe

On every page of my website, I have the following form in the sidebar (don't worry about the static values of the form):

```
<form target="booking_iframe" name="form1" method="post" action="/booking" id="le_booking_form">
<div class="form_row">CHECK IN
    <input name="side_check_in_date" type="text" class="stwths_input" id="checkin" value="2012-03-05">
</div>

<div class="form_row">CHECK OUT
    <input name="side_check_out_date" type="text" class="stwths_input" id="checkout" value="2012-03-10">
</div>

<div class="stwths_submit_box"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" class="stwths_submit" rel="follow"></div>

</form>
```

What the form needs to do is POST the `side_check_in_date` and `side_check_out_date` to an iFrame on the booking page which the form sends you to when you hit **Submit** so the user can fill in the form that appears on this booking page.

Here's the code from the booking page:

```
<iframe name="booking_iframe" src="http://thestrandreservation.spin-demo.com/?ptype=user_booking" width="690" height="3000" border="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You can see the home and booking pages below:

- http://thestrand.spin-demo.com/
- http://thestrand.spin-demo.com/booking

Comment: You can set the target of your form to the iframe. `<form target="booking_iframe">`

Comment: @imjp And it's working, right? I would love the book a residence BTW :-)

Comment: It's not working :p The resort is gorgeous, I'd love to stay there as well. haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the booking page, you need to insert value="{CHECK_IN_DATE}" and value="{CHECK_OUT_DATE}" into your form with the id="reservation_frm". That needs to happen server side, because you are posting this data from your stay_withus_form.

I don't know what server technology you are using, whether it's php, ruby, or .net it doesn't matter.

Then use Javascript on the booking page to submit the reservation_frm form:

using plain old Javascript:

```
document.forms["reservation_frm"].submit();
```

or using jQuery

```
$("#reservation_frm").submit();
```